# Memory management scenario with MongoDB & Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm implementing a medium scale marketing e-commerce affiliation site, which has following estimates,

```
Total Size of Data: 5 - 10 GB
Indexes on Data: 1 GB approx (which I wanted to be in memory)
Disk Size (fast I/O): 20-25 GB
Memory: 2 GB
App development: node.js

Working set estimation of Query: Average 1-2 KB, Maximum 20-30 KB of text base article
```

I'm trying to understand whether MongoDB would be right choice for database or not. Index is going to be fairly downsize of Memory but I have noticed that after querying that MongoDB, it has occupied the memory (size of result set) for caching query. In 8 hours I'm expecting that all queries' depth would cover almost 95% of data, in that scenario how will MongoDB manage limited memory scenario also app instance of node.js running on same server.

Would a MongoDB a right choice for this scenario or I should go for other JSON based no-SQL Databases.

Comment: Whether MongoDb could fit is based, normally, on the data itself and the queries used on it; what you have is an esitmation for working set

Comment: Working set estimation is 1-2 KB average, and maximum would be 20-30 KB of text article per page load query.

Comment: I've moved the question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47715/memory-management-scenario-with-mongodb-node-js apologies for posting to irelevent forum.